# PHP: Условие с выводом текста в середине строки

Tags: php

Здавствуйте, подскажите, как в переменную `$html` записать строку, в которой выполнялось бы условие установки `<input>` с флагом `checked`?

Нужно что-то вроде такого:

```
$a = '1';
$html = '<input type="radio" name="test" '     .  if($a){echo 'checked'}  .   '/>';
```

Но не работает, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать тернарный оператор:

```
$a = '1';
$html = '<input type="radio" name="test" '     .  ($a ? 'checked' : '')  .   '/>';
```

Подробнее о нем: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @rjhdby, Не подскажите, в чем у меня ошибка? Ради интереса, как переписать тоже самое без использования тернарного оператора?

Comment: Ну, как сказать... нельзя использовать языковую конструкцию в выражении. Когда вы используете оператор конкатенации строк "." - он ожидает, что ему дадут в качестве операндов значение, которое можно привести к строке (или просто строку). А конструкция - не является значением.

Comment: По поводу примера без тернарного оператора - ответ ниже как раз это и демонстрирует.

Comment: @Pavel Илья совершенно правильно ответил. Без тернарного в одну строку не получится. Либо, как вариант, 'checked'  === true, ''===false. То есть $a = 'checked' либо $a='', по необходимости, и его уже конкатенировать

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, по хорошему, следует избегать генерировать HTML разметку таким образом.

Так будет лучше.

```
<?php
$a='1';
?>
<input type="radio" name="test" <?php echo $a?'checked':'' ?>/>
```